# Python SpeechRecognition Library says my microphone is unavailable

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to do speech recognition using python and the library SpeechRecognition. When I run the basic code from the docs I get the error message shown below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__main__.py", line 8, in <module>
    with m as source: r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 141, in __enter__
    input=True,  # stream is an input stream
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 750, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 441, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
OSError: [Errno -9985] Device unavailable
```

I have tried using multiple microphone indexes but none of them pick anything up (program runs forever until I quit it), but when I try it with my default actual microphone it gives me the error.
When running `python -m speech_recognition` to test if it was installed in command prompt I got the same error message as shown above so the code is not an issue. I have also tried running the program as an admin and made sure my microphone was set as default. I also only have python 3 installed so it is not an issue with multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Boss.. plz say some")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print("143 Boss")
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Use this code, if you still face problem comment else accept the answer.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post the code is not the issue, along with that all you posted was the code from the documentation. However, I tried it anyway and it did not work.